# What are the 'best practices' if you need to edit a framework's code in order for it to do what you want?

Tags: frameworks, frontend, web-frameworks

I need a very specific feature that isn't supported by the framework I chose for my front-end project. I want to know what are the communities 'best practices' or guidelines for doing so.

Ex:

After integrating the Lumx UI framework (http://ui.lumapps.com/) for 2 weeks I find out the file-input controller component (http://ui.lumapps.com/components/file-input) doesn't have all of the features I need, like the directive doesn't allow me to use the 'accept attribute' type so I can't limit it to accept only 'csv' files. So...

1. I go into the the lumx.js file, find the file-input directive and alter it's code a little so I can get the results I need.
2. I save it (and it works!).
3. 5min goes by and I start to feel like I did something unspeakable and start to stress about the changes I just made getting wiped out in the event a future dev upgrades the current version of lumx and it breaks my interface...
4. I search around online but not sure how to phrase question well enough to get google to spit out the results so I post here...

Comment: So this isn't really a programming question but it looks like it has a github meaning open source meaning full access to the code.  This is good news for you.  You can essentially just fork the branch (I'm assuming master) that you made the changes to, Then every time the devs push a new version to their github, you just pull those changes into your forked version.  You could even talk with a dev and collaborate, but the point of open source software is so you can make changes as you need (barring license issues that you'd want to check into).

Comment: Thanks Michael. I guess my question relates to modifying open-source software in specifically a business environment, where other devs could inherity my code months or years later. So you suggest forking the project instead of just modifying the lone .js file and keeping a note somewhere?

Comment: Hi Scott.  Absolutely I would recommend that.  Keeping a note is very hard to track and if you were to ever leave who knows what could happen to that note.  Forking the project allows you to stay up to date without having to change that same line over and over again each time the devs push a new version of that library.  This might be overkill for a one line change but you could even develop the change more to allow a parameter to be passed to the method that could limit the accepted file input types.

Answer (score 1):

Michael gave you the right answer. Simply fork the LumX repository, make the change you need and don't hesitate to send a Pull Request back to LumX so that we can include your modifications (if that makes sense) to the final release.

If it's something that cannot make it to the release, you can then use your very own fork as a bower source and thus use your own version of LumX.
In this case, you have to keep in mind that you should regularly "update" your fork with the changes made in the origin repository (and may have some conflicts).

Once again, don't hesitate to open a Pull Request on LumX for bug fixes or changes that you think may be cool for the framework.
If you think that you encountered an issue and you are not sure of how to fix it, you can also open an issue on the repository and a developer of our team will try to solve it as soon as possible.

See you soon on LumX

Clément from Lumapps